# My MySQL database is not updating?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update my datebase from a php archive but i can't: 
Before you ask: The names from db are written correctly and the if works too...

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET["ans"]) && isset($_GET["name"])) 
{ 


include("con.php"); 
$con = con(); 
$answer = $_GET["ans"]; 
$nam = $_GET["name"]; 

if($answer="firefly" ||$answer="Firefly" ||$answer="FIREFLY") 

{ 

$le=2; 
$sc=50; 

$update = "UPDATE User SET Level='$le', Score='$sc' where Name = '$nam'"; 
mysql_query($update,$con); 


// header("Location: lv1b.php?n=$nam"); 

} 

else { 
echo "try again..." ; 
} 


} 


?>*
```

This is the con.php...

```
    <?php 
 function con() 
    {   $server="localhost";   $user="root";     $pass=""; 
    $con= mysql_connect($server, $user,$pass); 
    mysql_select_db("games");     return $con; 
    }
```

Comment: How does it not work? What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this? You're also wide open to SQL injections and using an obsolete API.

Comment: It doesn't update the level and score on MySQL...

Comment: You also have an error in your if statement.

Comment: What does mysql_error() say?

Comment: can we have the containing of `con();`

Comment: <?php
    function con()
    {
        $server="localhost";
        $user="root";
        $pass="";
        $con= mysql_connect($server, $user,$pass);
        mysql_select_db("games");
        return $con;
    }

Comment: You're doing an assignment `if($answer="firefly" ||$answer="Firefly" ||$answer="FIREFLY")` instead of a comparison `if($answer=="firefly" || $answer=="Firefly" || $answer=="FIREFLY")`

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement currently is assigning values, not testing equality, you can also skip the three tests by using one of the case conversion functions... so instead the `if` line should be:

```
if(strtolower($answer)=="firefly") {
```

Next up - as pointed out in comments - you're using the out-of-date MySQL library, you should rather be using [MySQLI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Also you're wide open to SQL injection, you should be escaping any value you're using in MySQLi see [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).  In your example this means escaping the value of `$nam`

A potential alternative script-fragment (using MySQLi and the above `if` statement changes) might look something like:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", /*username*/"root", /*pass*/"", /*dbname*/);

$name=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["name"]);

if (strtolower($_GET["ans"])=="firefly") {
  if (!$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET level='2',score='50' ".
                      "WHERE name='$name'")) {
    echo "query failed";
  } else {
    echo "Updated"
  }
  $mysqli->close();
} else {
  echo "try again..";
}
```